# Vagrant: SSL verification error behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, ssl, certificate, vagrant, ssl-certificate

My company uses a proxy.
I am using a Windows 10 notebook, 64 bit. Vagrant version 2.1.1.
When trying to install a Vagrant plugin, e.g.

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

I see the following error:

```
Installing the 'vagrant-proxyconf' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
ERROR: SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR: You must add /DC=net/DC=<MY_COMPANY>/DC=corp/CN=<CA-Name> to your local trusted store
Vagrant failed to load a configured plugin source. This can be caused by a variety of issues including: transient connectivity, proxy filtering rejecting access to a configured plugin source, or a configured plugin source not responding correctly. Please review the error message below to help resolve the issue:

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Source: https://rubygems.org/
```

I tried to the steps shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872591/how-to-use-vagrant-in-a-proxy-environment

```
set http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
set https_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

but that didn't help.

After exporting the certificate mentioned (I hope it was the correct one; there are two certs with the same name) above and adding it to
...\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\cacert.pem

(as suggested by [Installing vagrant plugin on the corporate network](https://superuser.com/questions/1122599/installing-vagrant-plugin-on-the-corporate-network/1136277)), I got another SSL error:

```
Installing the 'vagrant-proxyconf' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
ERROR: SSL verification error at depth 2: unable to get issuer certificate (2)
Vagrant failed to load a configured plugin source. This can be caused by a variety of issues including: transient connectivity, proxy filtering rejecting access to a configured plugin source, or a configured plugin source not responding correctly. Please review the error message below to help resolve the issue:

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Source: https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: There are probably multiple certificate stores in play. You need to add the proxy root certificate to all of them.

Comment: Do you know where I find that proxy root certificate?

Comment: Ask the IT department or save it using your web browser.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Daniel B. Our IT department had a couple of certificates which had to be appended to ...\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\cacert.pem
It's working fine now.